# Time capsule not backing up

Tags: time-machine, backup, time-capsule

Since many days, my time capsule, isn't making any backups. I checked the light status and its green, when choosen the command for backup now, it spends good amount of time (10-15 min) saying "preparing backup" and then failing, and upong entering "Time Capsule" preferences and choosing the red icon, I am showed the following message [image]

I tried restarting time capsule and my mac. But nothing works, My system is updated too. How can i fix this problem and why is it happening?

Comment: so did you use the disk utility as recommended to check the disk

Comment: @Buscar웃 yes, i already did prior to posting this. But nothing. infact i don't see my time capsule device in it.

Comment: then you did not repair it!

Answer (score 1):

It clearly advises you to use Disk Utility and repair your back up disk.

[image: time machine error]

Comment: I did that already, nothing happens.

Comment: If as you say you do not see the time capsule in disk utility, then you did not repair that drive.

Comment: is it a USB disk, or how is it connected during the Disk Utility process ?